# No matter what I do, upgrade keeps being offered

Tags: upgrade

I am very happily running 12.04.5 LTS

Several months ago, it began popping up a dialog box EVERY COUPLE OF MINUTES that says
"Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 'Trusty tahr'" -- there are three choices

- Don't upgrade,
- Ask me later, and
- Yes

I don't want to upgrade. But answering **Don't upgrade** doesn't help. The box keep popping up every couple of minutes. if I forget to log out and come back a couple of days later, I have hundreds of these dialogs!

In case this matters I'm logging in via a lan into xrdp, and i use the gnome session-fallback (not Unity)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure notifications for new versions from Software Sources, from dropdown menu **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version**, select **Never**

[image: Software Sources]

Comment: thanks. i will give that a go. (coincidentally my hard disk crashed yesterday so i can't try it out just now